# Unexpected token 'export' error messsage on JavaScript project

Tags: javascript, importerror

I was trying to copy a JavaScript code that I wrote on a online learning platform.
The code was 2 JavaScript files: Export and Import files.

**updated:** I tried adding to index.html: type = "module" **to both JavaScript files**

When I am running the src files now on VS code and using live server. It gives me some error messages on Chrome:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) airplane:1

When not on live server - Open index.html on chrome gives me the following error messages:

Access to script at 'file:///C:/web%20development/studies/frontend/js/test/src/missionControl.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
missionControl.js:1

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

index.html:1 Access to script at 'file:///C:/web%20development/studies/frontend/js/test/src/airplane.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
airplane.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

html code

```
<body>
    <script type = "module" src="./src/missionControl.js"></script>
    <script type = "module" src="./src/airplane.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

airplane.js

```
export let availableAirplanes = [
    {name: 'AeroJet',
     fuelCapacity: 800,
     availableStaff: ['pilots', 'flightAttendants', 'engineers', 'medicalAssistance', 'sensorOperators'],
     maxSpeed: 1200,
     minSpeed: 300
    }, 
    {name: 'SkyJet',
     fuelCapacity: 500,
     availableStaff: ['pilots', 'flightAttendants'],
     maxSpeed: 800,
     minSpeed: 200
    }
    ];

    export let flightRequirements = {
      requiredStaff: 4,
      requiredSpeedRange: 700
    };

    export function meetsStaffRequirements(availableStaff, requiredStaff) {
      if (availableStaff.length >= requiredStaff) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    };

    export function meetsSpeedRangeRequirements(maxSpeed, minSpeed, requiredSpeedRange) {
      let range = maxSpeed - minSpeed;
      if (range > requiredSpeedRange) {
        return true;
        } else {
        return false;
      }
    };

    export default meetsSpeedRangeRequirements;
```

missionControl.js

```
import{ availableAirplanes, flightRequirements, meetsStaffRequirements } from './airplane';
import meetsSpeedRangeRequirements from './airplane';

function displayFuelCapacity() {
  availableAirplanes.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log('Fuel Capacity of ' + element.name + ': ' + element.fuelCapacity);
  });
}

displayFuelCapacity();

function displayStaffStatus() {
  aircavailableAirplanesrafts.forEach(function(element) {
   console.log(element.name + ' meets staff requirements: ' + meetsStaffRequirements(element.availableStaff, flightRequirements.requiredStaff) );
  });
}

displayStaffStatus();

function displaySpeedRangeStatus() {
  availableAirplanes.forEach(function(element) {
   console.log(element.name + ' meets speed range requirements:' + meetsSpeedRangeRequirements(element.maxSpeed, element.minSpeed, flightRequirements.requiredSpeedRange));
  });
}

displaySpeedRangeStatus();
```

Comment: Hello, could you share your code on github/gitlab/other? This is to see the project structure and configuration.

Comment: https://github.com/urigross/test.git

Thank you !

Comment: You did add `type=module`, but to only one of your `<script>`s. You have two of them!

Comment: @Bergi : Thanks for letting me know - I didn't know I have to add the module type on both import and export javaScript files. I updates my question with a new error Message. I hope you could further assisting me. Thank you ! Maybe It's the LiveServer causing the prolem ?

Comment: "*the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)*" - that's because you're importing the file from `/src/airplaine`, but it is located at `/src/airplane.js`. Add the `.js` file ending to the import statements in *missionControl.js*.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you so much. The website I was learning from did not appoint this as a mistake but I am surely now understand the logic for next time. Thanks again :)